# How do I access a specific value in this dictionary of JSON using Swift?

Tags: json, swift, api

I am trying to get the total Wins from this API (Tracker Network API) and I have gotten the key and it displays the key and value like so.

[image]

The code is below and I am also able to get the number of wins (Integer) along with these values(Titles). However, I cannot figure out how to just get the "Wins" number without having all the other numbers printing out too.

I have tried

```
print(statsArray[8])
 totalWins = statsArray[8]
 //["value": 4350, "key": Wins]
 print(totalWins.values)
 //[Wins, 4350]
```

but it does not print it how I would like it to print. I would like it to print out as just the number so that I can then load that number into a UILabel.

What I am asking, is how do I print the "Wins" (integer) amount only and not the other 11 json outputs? I just want one of the numbers.

```
let epicName = "Ninja"
let formattedName = epicName.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "%20")                   
let platform = "pc"
//pc, xbl, psn


let fortniteChallengesURL3 = URL(string: "https://api.fortnitetracker.com/v1/profile/\(platform)/\(formattedName)")
if let unwrappedURL = fortniteChallengesURL3 {
var request = URLRequest(url: unwrappedURL)
request.addValue("MyKey", forHTTPHeaderField: "TRN-Api-Key")
let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

    if let data = data {
        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as! [String:Any]
            //print(json)



            for (key, value) in json {


                if (key == "lifeTimeStats") {
                    if let statsArray:[ [String : Any] ] = value as? [ [String : Any] ] {

                        //accessing the 8th but I am getting the output wrong
                        /*let firstKey = Array( (value as? [ [String : Any] ])!)[8]
                        */

                        print(statsArray[8])
                        let totalWins = statsArray[8]
                        //["value": 4350, "key": Wins]
                        print(totalWins.values)
                        //[Wins, 4350]

                        for dict in statsArray {
                            for (key, value) in dict {

                                if (key == "key") {
                                    //print ( "\(firstKey.values)")

                                    print ( "keys are     \(value)")


                                }
                                /*if (key == "value") {
                                    print ( "value are     \(value)")


                                }*/
                            }
                        }

                    }


                }

            }



        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)

            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() ) {

            }
        }
    }
}
dataTask.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TotalWins is a dictionary with two items and you can access any item value in a dictionary by its key, so try this:

```
print(totalWins["value"])
```

Answer (score 0):

When you iterate over each item in the array of dictionaries you can access the key and the value fields directly like so:

```
for dic in statsArray {
     let title = dic["key"]
     let value = dic["value"] // You can use this as the value for the label
}
```

If you want to only access the total wins data, you could do:

```
let totalWinsValues = totalWins["value"]
```

You will want to look into creating a data model in the form of a struct of a class, and implementing the Codable protocol to make things easier and cleaner.